# jQuery world clocks for future date & time

Tags: jquery, future, clock

I would like to show dates and times for different international locations for a future date and time.

I will use a simple text display for the different locations, like this page does. https://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php

I don't know how to modify existing world clock codes to show a future date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and their [time zone plugin](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) to easily get the date a certain number of days, hours, etc in the future and then convert that into another time zone.

```
moment().add(1, “days”).tz(“America/New_York”);
```

**Edit:** Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLkbpcr9/) I made which has modifications (explained in comments) to the code you posted below.

Comment: I use jQuery dtpicker to select a future datetime, and use moment to find the difference between current & future dt.  
    `var d2 = new Date( moment(document.getElementById(target).value) );    
    var diff = moment().diff(d2);` 
Add the difference to the current dt, show other time zone  
  
    `var myresult = 'SC Time ' + moment(d2).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");  
    myresult += '<br>LA Time ' + moment.tz(target, "America/Los_Angeles").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a");`  
  
How does that look to you?

Comment: @user3315297 I made some changes to your code, see my edit above for more info. I'm not sure how it works with your jQuery UI implementation, but you can report back and let me know if that helps anyway

Comment: Awesome, much simpler than I had thought. I was getting the same result for all TZs but I was using  moment-tz.js not moment-timezone-with-data.js, I noticed that looking at your jsfiddle, Thank You Very Much for the excellent, clear help. You saved me a lot of time. Moment is really impressive. Best Regards, Mike

Comment: @user3315297 No problem, I'm happy to help Mike! Could you do me a favor and click the check mark to mark my answer as accepted?